# Сортировка json-строки по алфавиту перед загрузкой

Tags: jquery, json, сортировка

Есть json-строка следующего вида:

```
[  
    {  
        "code":"NC",
        "name":"New Caledonia",
        "currency":"XPF",
        "name_translations":{  
            "de":"Neukaledonien",
            "en":"New Caledonia",
            "zh-CN":"新喀里多尼亚",
            "tr":"Yeni Kaledonya",
            "ru":"Новая Каледония",
            "fr":"Nouvelle-Calédonie",
            "es":"Nueva Caledonia",
            "it":"Nuova Caledonia",
            "th":"ประเทศนิวแคลิโดเนีย"
        }
    },
    {  
        "code":"MT",
        "name":"Malta",
        "currency":"EUR",
        "name_translations":{  
            "de":"Malta",
            "en":"Malta",
            "zh-CN":"马耳他",
            "tr":"Malta",
            "ru":"Мальта",
            "fr":"Malte",
            "es":"Malta",
            "it":"Malta",
            "th":"ประเทศมอลตา"
        }
    }
]
```

И есть скрипт, который загружает json-файл и каждое его значение добавляет в список:

```
$.getJSON('/json/countries.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, field){
        $('#jelectTool1').jelect('addValue', field['code'], field['name_translations']['ru']);
    });
});
```

**Вопрос:** можно ли как-то перед добавлением всех значений в список отсортировать их по алфавиту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('/json/countries.json', function(data) {
  data.sort(function(a, b) { 
    var aStr = a['name_translations']['ru'];
    var bStr = b['name_translations']['ru'];
    if (aStr > bStr)
      return 1;
    else if (aStr < bStr)
      return -1;
    else
      return 0;
  });
  $.each(data, function(i, field){
    $('#jelectTool1').jelect('addValue', field['code'], field['name_translations']['ru']);
  });
});
```